# Specify account for single gsutil call

Tags: gsutil

I want to be able to perform simultaneous `gsutil` calls against Google Cloud Storage, using different accounts.

For that purpose, I'd like to know if there is a way to specify a Google Cloud account for a single `gsutil` call, i.e. something similar to `gcloud`'s `--account` option:

```
> gcloud --account $account_1 $command_1
> gcloud --account $account_2 $command_2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if gsutil supports account name and credentials files as an argument but the closest solution I can come up with is activating an account, and if successfuly making a gsutil call -

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=project1.json && gsutil ls
 gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=project2.json && gsutil ls`

You can also setup multiple accounts in a config file and switch between accounts - this link might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409499/how-can-i-use-gsutil-with-multiple-accounts

Comment: I see what you mean, that's a good idea :) . I upvoted, but Imma not accept your answer though, in case someone comes up with something better

Answer (score 1):

There exists `gcloud alpha storage` which has some of gsutil's functionality and supports the `--account` flag.